# Excel file path doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Have this (and it works):

```
if (Sport == "Athletics")
            {
                excel_init("C:/Users/Dries Canfyn/Desktop/score/ScoretableMenAthletics.xlsx");
            }
```

but now I want to include the excel file in my project.

The excel file is now in a folder called IO, which is in the same folder as my class where this 'if' is in. How can I reach the excel file? What path should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Determine your `WorkingDirectory` and then use a relative path from there.
Usually the `WorkingDirectory` is where your **.exe** resides, but it depends on how you started your process. Then you can use a relative path like

```
if (Sport == "Athletics")
     {
         excel_init("IO/ScoretableMenAthletics.xlsx");
     }
```

I don't know what happens inside your `excel_init`, but consider [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx), `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory Property`:

When the UseShellExecute property is false, gets or sets the working directory for the process to be started. When UseShellExecute is true, gets or sets the directory that contains the process to be started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method "resource file" board to add and access your files in a project easily.
This is one of many possibilities.

After adding the file in your project.

1. Top right click on the file and click property
2. In the file properties change "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource"
3. And "Copy to Output directory" to "Copy if never"

Each time you compile your project, the file is added and achievable during its execution. Like this.

```
//Get the full path of the application directory "release / debug" depending on your compiler.
string currentPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
excel_init(currentPath + @"IO\ScoretableMenAthletics.xlsx");
```

Picture to "edit build action" and "copy to output directory

[image: "":]

I hope this help you

Comment: Thanks! But I can't find it yet, When I print the path (currentPath + "IO/ScoretableMenAthletics.xlsx") I got this: "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Desktop\Visual Studio 2010\Project\Project.WebUI\IO/ScoretableMenAthletics.xlsx"  Maybe the error is that the first backslashes or like this: "\" ?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's a small mistake on my part, tried to change the path like this -> string fileName = @"IO\ScoretableMenAthletics.xlsx"     I edited my answer

Comment: It still doesn't work, can you think of another reason why it doesn't work? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Server.MapPath`

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/IO/ScoretableMenAthletics.xlsx");
```